# For a normal population with a mean ofµ and a standard deviation of 9, the hypotheses to be tested are H0: µ = 50 versus H1: µ < 50.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Which would result in the highest power? (D)
A. µ1 = 49; n =10

B. µ1 = 48; n =10

C. µ1 = 49; n =100

D. µ1 = 48; n =100

E. µ1 = 48.5; n =15

The answer is D.

So far I got

x^= 50 - za 9/sqrt n

I know I have to standardize for beta, but there's not confidence level stated so I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do any serious calculation for this.  You can use process of elimination.  The farther $\mu_1$ is from $\mu_0$, the higher the power.  The larger $n$ is, the higher the power.  So this eliminates all choices except (D):  compared to every other answer choice, (D) has a difference $|\mu_1 - \mu_0|$ that is at least as large and an $n$ that is at least as large.

The only way that the question becomes "difficult" is if, among the answer choices, you could not find one that is unequivocally "better" than the others; for example, if you had to choose between only options (B) and (C), it is no longer clear which of the two has larger power because while $|\mu_1 - \mu_0| = 2$ for (B) and $1$ for (C), the standard error of the test statistic for (C) is substantially smaller than for (B).  In such a case, you would need to do more computation.